# Is there any way to connect to Windows PowerShell from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, login, remote-access, remote

I want to access a Windows machine from Ubuntu. I don't want to connect with to the GUI (rdesktop) - instead I want to connect to Windows PowerShell from the terminal.

This is because I want to administer the Windows machine similarly to how you can administer a headless Linux server: running background jobs, writing shell scripts to perform daily/weekly remote maintenance, shutting down/logging off thru shell scripts.

Will rlogin work, and if so how? If not, what other options are there?

Comment: This question would be better if you explain why you don't want to use rdesktop.

Answer (score 6):

There's a commercial proprietary tool called [PowerShell SSH Server](http://www.powershellinside.com) ([read TechNet description](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff808410.aspx)) that will let you log in over SSH.

There's also a free proprietary tool [freeSSHd](http://www.freesshd.com) - you can run it [and replace the standard `cmd` command shell with PowerShell](http://hindenes.com/trondsworking/2012/05/17/run-powershell-through-ssh/).

Finally, if you'd prefer a free software (open source) solution, you can [install the Cygwin SSH server and run PowerShell under that](http://hivearchive.com/2006/07/03/using-powershell-through-ssh/). (Apparently this is slower.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [WinSSHD from Bitvise](http://www.bitvise.com/winsshd) and set the Terminal shell for each allowed user as "powershell.exe".